# Logic in pandas apply function not as expected

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe in which I construct a list of values as such:

```
data_df["items"] = data_df.apply(
    lambda x: [x["item_1"], x["item_2"]]
    if x["item_2"]
    else [x["item_1"]],
    axis=1,
)
```

In my mind this approach should construct a list containing items 1 and 2 if `item_2` exist otherwise it should just construct a list containing item_1. However, the check on `item_2` doesn't seem to work as expected. I have tried checking for `None` values as well as empty strings. How do I write this so that the following happens:

if `item_1` and `item_2` are None or "" return []

if `item_1` is not None but `item_2` is None or "" return [`item_1`]

if `item_1` and `item_2` return [`item_1`, `item_2`]

Also, `item_1` and `item_2` are strings

Comment: [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `pd.isna()`:

```
df['item_list'] = df[['item1', 'item2']].apply(lambda x: [i for i in x if not pd.isna(i)], 1)
```

update:

```
df['item_list'] = df[['item1', 'item2']].apply(lambda x: [i for i in x if not (pd.isna(i) or i == '')], 1)
```

Comment: This is close @Nk03. However, I still get [`item_1`, ""]. Is it possible to avoid the empty string?

Comment: Add one more condition for an empty string values.